# Adding file extensions to iOS document manager

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentbrowservc

I’m using the default iOS file manager for a Swift application. I’m writing the class for a UIDocumentBrowserViewController and I want the whole file name to show. For example rather than Untitled, I want Untitled.txt. Or rather than script, script.py.

As a side note, I notice that the actual files app does not have functionality to show the extension.

Comment: I apologize for poor formatting, will edit question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes its worth to check apple documentation) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

As I see it is possible to show file's extension, with help of `var shouldShowFileExtensions: Bool` from UIDocumentBrowserViewController. But to our sorrow it's available only from iOS 13.0+.

And as Apple says about this property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller/3153159-shouldshowfileextensions

> The default value is false.
>
> This property has no effect in iPad apps running in macOS.

Comment: I appreciate it. I saw nothing online because it is still in beta. And I looked through the documentation, but the current one (not the beta one). Cheers

Comment: This is all nice to read, but in practice it doesn't do anything. Adding `.shouldShowFileExtensions = true` still doesn't show filenames. So frustrating. Why would anyone NOT want to show filenames is beyond my imagination... It just adds confusion.